# How can I disable skrollr plugin while modal is open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

So I'm using skrollr.js for a website, and I need to be able to open a modal  window, at which point I want to disable the user from scrolling while the modal is open as they wouldn't be able to see the animations that were being activated as they scrolled.

https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you show some of your code I would be able to provide a better solution but have you tried something like...

```
$('#show-modal').click(function(){

   $('#modal').fadeIn(500, function(){
       $('body').css({'overflow':'hidden'});
   });

});

$('#hide-modal').click(function(){

   $('#modal').fadeOut(500, function(){
       $('body').css({'overflow':'visible'});
   });

});
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! I was making it too complicated :)